# Class Interval Ambiguity

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose we have to take a class interval of 5. Starting form 45 what would be my correct classes?
45-50,51-56,57-62    or
45-49,50-54,55-59

Answer (score 3):

The first series (45-50, 51-56, 57-62) you proposed has intervals of 6, not 5. For example, from 45 to 50, there are 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, and 50, i.e. 6 numbers. The other series you proposed (45-49, 50-54, 55-59) would work.